# Modifying FASTA headers with Unix command line tools

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, fasta

I'm stuck again with modifying text. I want to alter large text files such as these:

```
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_691 range=chr1:8121498-8121502 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATGG
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_690 range=chr1:8121587-8121591 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATAG
```

to

```
>chr1:8121498-8121502 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATGG
>chr1:8121587-8121591 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATAG
```

I have been using `sed '/^>/s/[^ ]* />/'` which removes the first part (`>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_690`) but I'm really stuck on how to remove the `range=`. I've tried various combinations of `//` and `grep` but no joy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line:

```
sed 's/[^=>]*=//' file
```

test with your input:

```
kent$  echo ">hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_691 range=chr1:8121498-8121502 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATGG
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_690 range=chr1:8121587-8121591 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATAG"|sed 's/[^=>]*=//'
>chr1:8121498-8121502 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATGG
>chr1:8121587-8121591 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATAG
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these variety of shell commands =)

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk -F'range=' '/^>/{print ">" $2}' file
```

Or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
 sed '/^>/s/.*range=(.*)/>\1/' file
```

Comment: These do not work correctly since they will leave out the ">" character. The awk and the GNU grep with perl regex will leave out the non-">" lines too...

Comment: post edited accordingly. Misunderstood your question, sorry ;)

Comment: You probably `sed -E` for BSD sed or GNU sed (or `sed -r` for GNU sed) for ERE ...